# Pointwise limit and determining uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am hoping that I could get feedback on my solution for the following problem.

> Find the pointwise limit of the sequence $f_n$ and determine whether the convergence is uniform or not. $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} nx^2 \quad & \text{if } \ x \in [0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}], \\
> 0 \quad & \text{if } \ x \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},1]. \\ \end{cases}  
> $$

Note first that $f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$. Let $x>0$, then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $x>\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ and $\forall n \geq N$, $x>\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Hence, for $0<x<1 \rightarrow f_n(x)=0$. Thus the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ is $f(x)=0$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=1 \neq 0$. Therefore, $f_n(x) \nrightarrow^{u} f(x)$ on $[0,1]$.

Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: What is $f (1/\sqrt {n}) ?$

Comment: To me it's fine. You should precise which value takes $f_n$ at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @Joseph I ask the same question. what is $f (1/ sqrt n) $ ?

Comment: @Joseph As it stands you have the functions taking two different values at $1/\sqrt{n}$ which means they aren't properly defined functions. Just cause it's discontinuous doesn't mean you can get away with it not being a well-defined function. (That being said, whether you handle the discontinuity by picking the right value or the left value doesn't particularly matter.)

Comment: There was an error in the question, I have updated the function. It is defined to be 0 for $x \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},1]$.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima, $f_n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint for U convergence**

for $n>0$,

$$f_n (\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}})=1$$
and
$$f (\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}})=0$$

$$M_n=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f (x)|\geq $$
$$|f_n (\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}})-f (\frac {1}{\sqrt{n}})|=1$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}M_n\ge 1$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}M_n \ne 0$$

the convergence is not uniform at $[0,1] $.

Comment: Thank you, your hint helps me with my understanding and gives me a different approach for similar problems, +1 and accepted answer.